# Добавление баннера AdMob в приложение, написанное на AIDE

Tags: android, admob, реклама, aide

Написал простенькую игру с помощью AIDE, теперь хочу добавить рекламу. Возможно ли это сделать прямо в AIDE, или без PC не обойтись?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, можно воспользоваться описанным здесь способом: http://gamedevblogs.ru/blog/fgl/1860.html

Существует бесплатный сервис, называется FGL Enhance ZeroCode. У него есть возможность встроить рекламу в любой .apk файл. Это может быть постоянно висящий баннер (и обновляющийся согласно тех настроек, которые были указаны в адмобе при его создании) или реклама, показываемая перед стартом приложения.

1. Заходим на https://enhance.fgl.com/
2. Выбираем "I want to choose SDK myself" -> AdMob
3. В технологии разработки выбираем Other. Для некоторых технологий (Unity, Java, Obj-C, Haxe и Air) есть возможность через отдельную библиотеку управлять появлением/скрытием баннера, но в данном случае рассмотрим вариант с постоянно висящим баннером, для которого никаких манипуляций с кодом на вашей стороне не требуется
4. Выбираем тип баннера: Persistent Banner и можем указать, сверху или снизу экрана его показывать
5. загружаем свой апк
6. задаём свой идентификатор баннера, полученный от АдМоба при регистрации и указываем тип баннера (проще всего задать SMART_BANNER, он занимает всю ширину, а высота будет 32, 50 или 90 пикселей,в зависимости от размера экрана)
7. Выбираем метод подписывания приложения после вшивания в него кода SDK AdMob. Можно скачать неподписанное приложение, а подписать локально. А можно доверить подпись самой системе Enhance, загрузив свой сертификат разработчика. Сама компания FGL - с репутацией, была одним из столпов инди-сообщества ещё во время "золотого века" веб-разработки, так что в принципе можно доверить это.
8. Скачиваем приложение со встроенным баннером. Если выбирали подписывание своим сертификатом на сервере - можно сразу отправлять в сторы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Готово, расширил ответ